# Query to bring data day and night sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query that brings the information of temperature and relative humidity per minute of a particular area:

```
SELECT plands.land AS Land,
   ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS Temperatureday,
   ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS Humidityday,
   WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week
FROM meteorology
INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
  AND TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00'
  AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00'
GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
         WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
         YEAR(meteorology.date)
UNION ALL
SELECT plands.land AS Land,
       ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS TemperatureNight,
       ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS HumidityNight,
       WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week
FROM meteorology
INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
  AND (TIME(meteorology.date) < '06:00:00'
       OR TIME(meteorology.date) > '18:00:00')
GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
         WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
         YEAR(meteorology.date)
```

It shows the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
  Land    |    Temperatureday  |   Humidityday  |  Week  |
----------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1    |         16.13      |     92.03      |  37    |
----------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1    |         16.46      |     84.35      |  38    | 
----------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1    |         9.37       |     99.0       |  37    |
----------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1    |         9.95       |     99.0       |  38    | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

but I what to show the data as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Land | Temperatureday  | Humidityday |TemperatureNight | HumidityNigh |Week|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1 |   16.13         |   92.03     |     9.37        |     99.0     | 37 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LAND1 |   16.46         |   84.35     |     9.95        |     99.0     | 38 | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that my query is wrong, but I don´t know what I do.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the `PRIMARY` and `UNIQUE` keys in `meteorology`?

Comment: the `PRIMARY` key in  meteorology` is `meteorology.id`

Comment: Any `UNIQUE` keys? Particularly, are there multiple observations in the day or night of any given date? And why `id_tenant` for the night data and not the day data?

Comment: I am sorry `id_tenant` shouldn´t be there, I already edit the question, and `meteorology` haven´t `UNIQUE` key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Subquery for the day data, to which night data is joined

Another way to join the data involves a subquery for the day data, to which you `JOIN` the night data as additional details with a second outer query. This works well in query engines that materialize a subquery into a temporary table, such as MySQL.

```
SELECT wxday.Land, Temperatureday, Humidityday,
       ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS TemperatureNight,
       ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS HumidityNight,
       wxday.Week
FROM (
  SELECT plands.land AS Land,
     ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS Temperatureday,
     ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS Humidityday,
     WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week,
     YEAR(meteorology.date) AS Year
  FROM meteorology
  INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
  WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
    AND TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00'
    AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00'
  GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
           WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
           YEAR(meteorology.date)
) AS wxday
INNER JOIN meteorology
ON (wxday.Land = meteorology.id_land
    AND WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) = wxday.Week
    AND YEAR(meteorology.date) = wxday.Year)
WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
  AND (TIME(meteorology.date) < '06:00:00'
       OR TIME(meteorology.date) > '18:00:00')
GROUP BY wxday.Land, wxday.Week, wxday.Year
```

### Union of two tables with different nonnull columns

A second approach keeps the `UNION`, putting day and night data in separate output columns and using `MIN` to combine them afterward. This works because the `MIN` of a group with one nonnull value and one `NULL` is the one nonnull value. It may work better in cases where some weeks have night data but no day data or vice versa:

```
SELECT Land,
       MIN(Temperatureday) AS Temperatureday,
       MIN(Humidityday) AS Humidityday,
       MIN(TemperatureNight) AS TemperatureNight,
       MIN(HumidityNight) AS HumidityNight,
       Week
FROM (
  SELECT plands.land AS Land,
     ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS Temperatureday,
     ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS Humidityday,
     NULL AS TemperatureNight,
     NULL AS HumidityNight,
     WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week,
     YEAR(meteorology.date) AS Year
  FROM meteorology
  INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
  WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
    AND TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00'
    AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00'
  GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
           WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
           YEAR(meteorology.date)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT plands.land AS Land,
         NULL AS TemperatureNight,
         NULL AS HumidityNight,
         ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS TemperatureNight,
         ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS HumidityNight,
         WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week,
         YEAR(meteorology.date) AS Year
  FROM meteorology
  INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
  WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
    AND (TIME(meteorology.date) < '06:00:00'
         OR TIME(meteorology.date) > '18:00:00')
  GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
           WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
           YEAR(meteorology.date)
) AS itsownalias
GROUP BY Land, Week, Year
```

## Excluding from an average using conditional null

A third approach makes one pass through the data and uses `AVG`, relying on its identical `NULL`-skipping behavior. This can also be expressed without a subquery, but `IsDay` makes it more readable and more in line with the ["Don't repeat yourself" principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
SELECT Land,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE IsDay WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE temperature END),2) AS Temperatureday,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE IsDay WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE humidity END),2) AS Humidityday,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE IsDay WHEN 0 THEN temperature ELSE NULL END),2) AS TemperatureNight,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE IsDay WHEN 0 THEN humidity ELSE NULL END),2) AS HumidityNight,
       WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week
FROM (
  SELECT plands.land AS Land,
     meteorology.temperature,
     meteorology.humidity,
     WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week,
     YEAR(meteorology.date) AS Year,
     CASE WHEN TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00'
               AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00'
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsDay
  FROM meteorology
  INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
  WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
) AS itsownalias
GROUP BY Land,
         WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
         YEAR(meteorology.date)
```

Comment: Thank you it works! :) I learned something new! you're great!

Answer (score 2):

Join your 2 queries instead of unioning them:

```
SELECT day.Week, day.land,
 day.Temperature, day.Humidity,
 night.Temperature, night.Humidity,
FROM
(
SELECT plands.land AS Land,
  ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS Temperature,
  ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS Humidity,
  WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week
FROM meteorology
INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
  AND TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00'
  AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00'
GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
     WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
     YEAR(meteorology.date)
) day LEFT JOIN (
SELECT plands.land AS Land,
   ROUND(AVG(meteorology.temperature),2) AS Temperature,
   ROUND(AVG(meteorology.humidity),2) AS Humidity,
   WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date) AS Week
FROM meteorology
INNER JOIN plands ON plands.id = meteorology.id_land
WHERE DATE(meteorology.date) BETWEEN '2016-09-12' AND '2016-09-23'
  AND (TIME(meteorology.date) < '06:00:00'
   OR TIME(meteorology.date) > '18:00:00')
  AND meteorology.id_tenant = 1
GROUP BY meteorology.id_land,
     WEEKOFYEAR(meteorology.date),
     YEAR(meteorology.date)
) night
ON day.land=night.land
AND day.Week=Night.Week
```

Note that this is not very efficient, and a better solution would be to implement a single pass through the data - but the code for this is rather messy....something along the lines of....

```
SELECT plands.land as Land,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00' 
       AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00' 
         THEN meteorology.temperature
       ELSE 0 END) 
       /
       SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(meteorology.date) >= '06:00:00' 
       AND TIME(meteorology.date) <= '18:00:00' 
         THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END), 2) AS DayTemperature,
  ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to answer in 4 minutes. The first one was ready the second was in preparation :). It should be noted that with the first approach , if data is missing for  for day or night the whole land/week line will vanish so not optimal. Also in the second approach you made SUM instead of AVG